# How can I add a newline only after the last iteration of a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, newline

This is a program that prints the first input integer value and prints every tenth value on the same line with a space between them until reaching the last value wherein I would like it to print the last value followed by a newline. The problem is that it is not printing the new line after the last value.
To be clear I do not desire a newline printed if 'second integer can't be less than the first' is printed, nor do I want a newline if the input values are equal. Only in the special case that int1 < int2 do I desire a newline and only after the last iteration.

```
int1 = int(input())
int2 = int(input())

if int2 < int1:
    print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.')
else:
    while int1 <= int2:
        print(int1, end = ' ')
        int1 += 10
```

Thanks in advance for any help y'all can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
int1 = int(input())
int2 = int(input())

if int2 < int1:
    print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.')
else:
    while int1 <= int2:
        print(int1, end = ' ')
        int1 += 10
    else:    #prints a newline when the while loop has completed iteration.
        print()
```

There is no need to include any other variable or a complicated code.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!! Thank you. Though I'm sure other answers would have gotten me the same result, all of them were overly complicated and included syntax that has not yet been covered in my course. This teaches me (reminds me) that else statements can be used with while statements to declare an alternative situation. Thank you, friend!

Comment: Glad I could help!!

Comment: @Drkdeibs, this doesn't do what you specified, "nor do I want a newline if the input values are equal", how is it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Simply print a newline after the while loop finishes. You'll note that "after the last iteration" is "after the finish of" anyway.

Comment: I guess I could have been more clear. There cannot be a newline printed if 'second integer can't be less than the first' is printed, nor can there be a newline if the input values are equal. Only in the special case that int1 < int2 do I desire a newline

Comment: In that case, save the original value of int1 and just print the newline if the original int1 value is less than int2.

Comment: Drkdeibs: Just put the `print()` right after the `while` loop indented to the same level.

Comment: That'll make it print the newline if int1 == int2, though, which is not desired.

Comment: @Drkdeibs: Change the `else:` to `elif int1 < int2:` so neither the `while` nor the following `print` are executed unless the precondition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [linspace()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4krvQ2u7pAhVmUN8KHY5mCocQFjADegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnumpy.org%2Fdoc%2F1.18%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.linspace.html&usg=AOvVaw27752Qb2HVFzSYUqailjz-) from numpy for that:

```
import numpy as np

int1 = int(input())
int2 = int(input())
nu = (int2-int1)*10+1

print(*np.linspace(int1,int2,num=nu))
```

Input:

```
4
10
```

Output:

```
4.0 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.7 4.8 4.9 5.0 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5 5.6 5.7 5.8 5.9 6.0 6.1 6.2 6.3 6.4 6.5 6.6 6.7 6.8 6.9 7.0 7.1 7.2 7.3 7.4 7.5 7.6 7.7 7.8 7.9 8.0 8.1 8.2 8.3 8.4 8.5 8.6 8.7 8.8 8.9 9.0 9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.6 9.7 9.8 9.9 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
int1 = int(input())
int2 = int(input())

if int1 > int2:
    print("Second integer can't be less than the first.")
elif int1 == int2:
    print(f"{int1} ", end='')
else:
    print(" ".join(map(str, range(int1, int2 + 1, 10))))
```

Comment: Ignoring the newline details, in the OP's algorithm, `int1 == int2` should just output `int1`, but yours outputs `int1` and `int1 + 10`.  What extra insight are you working with here?

Comment: Instead of `print(" ".join(map(str, range(int1, int2 + 11, 10))))` how about simply `print(*range(int1, int2 + 11, 10), sep=' ')` instead?  Though I'd use `1` instead of `11` as noted in my previous comment, your sequence goes one element beyond the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you describe:

```
int1 = int(input())
int2 = int(input())

if int2 < int1:
    print("Second integer can't be less than the first.")
else:
    int3 = int1  # don't change int1 as it's needed later

    while int3 <= int2:
        print(int3, end=' ')
        int3 += 10

    if int1 < int2:
        print()
```

Though the `int1 == int2` output is less than clean newline-wise so it may not be what you desire.  If you want to show that the newline printing after the final iteration is closely coupled with the `while` loop, you could do something like:

```
    while int3 <= int2:
        print(int3, end=' ')
        int3 += 10
    else:
        if int1 < int2:
            print()
```

But this is as likely to confuse as clarify.